# Bilingual WooCommerce Multivendor frontend Bilingual Wordpress Problem

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, customization, multilingual, wordpress-capabilities

I have a bilingual wordpress having `WCMarketPlace` with `Advanced Frontend Manager` dashboard for vendors. Since the vendors do not have access to Admin panel (the dashboard urls are like `domain/dashboard`), the translation tools to aid bilingual (multilingual) translations do not help. I tried `TranslatePress` and `qTranslate`. But I have not yet figured out how to trick the plugins to work for the forms in the domain.com/dashboard

The `qTranslate` has a [Guideline](https://github.com/qtranslate/qtranslate-xt/wiki/Integration-Guide) to enable the plugin to work at frontend via their `i18n-config.json`, where you can add necessary locations in JSON format. But even the [current plugin owner does not have a clue](https://github.com/qtranslate/qtranslate-xt/issues/585) how to do that.

Looks to me there is a way to enable the plugin to work at custom places and that would require a bit of understanding of the path and essential import/loading of plugin scripts along with jQuery. Also the forms having the common class also need to be binded with the LSB (Language Switch Button). They have a guideline to enable LSB to [custom fields](https://github.com/qtranslate/qtranslate-xt/wiki/FAQ#custom-fields) too.

Also, there is a nice feature with TranslatePress that they support different image/gallery for each language! So, I am curious if there's any way to integrate one of these plugins to work in the frontend. qTranslate mainly would need JS support to format the input fields. But TranslatePress would require both of its backend and frontend support at the vendor dashboard.

[Update] Reviewers might be confused as I have spoken about two plugins. First one qTranslate only requires frontEnd JS to enable forms to hold both language with a switch only. Thats why adding it could be easier than the later one. This solution would be better than not having any.
Second plugin (TranslatePress) has that extra feature that saves image/gallery for each language, which is unique and very ideal to have. But this plugin would require both backend and frontend includes to be present within the logged in /dashboard.
In general words, seeking at least a solution to bring at least the frontend logic to a frontend end-point (ie /dashboard). Or, to be able to bring in whole capability of backend and frontend logic of a plugin.

[Is asking for more than one solution too broad?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402142/is-asking-for-solutions-to-a-problem-that-has-more-than-one-possible-solution-to?cb=1)

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to translate a WordPress website, including WordPress theme and plugins, the text you want to translate needs to use WordPress [localization function](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/).

All of WordPress translation plugins rely on WordPress localization functions.

So if the form you want to translate was build by yourself, you will need to use that localization functions to be able to translate texts.

If you are using a third party form plugin, you need to check if the author of the plugin support internationalization.

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I have used localization feature successfully for plugins and even whole wordpress. What I am looking is aided translation in the forms with the aid from its roled users/admins.

Comment: In other words, lets say the owner and the providers of an website who are basically from a 2nd language but using another prominent language as primary but knows exactly how their product, posts, etc would be best stated in the secondary language.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the loco translate's plugin ? It does great the job when you need to translate any kind of theme or plugin directly on your website. You can also create configuration files for each of yours plugins, so that you can give any specific translation to what you want.

Comment: Yes, but I really do not need Loco. I had been using PoEdit for such purposes and that does everything Loco does. What I stated in the question is, looking for a solution to enable the frontend users (who has a role like vendors) to allow their product entries in a bilingual manner.